# mysqldump showing size zero byte , if it is scheduled by cronjob in linux

Tags: shell, mysql

`Mysqldump` is showing size zero byte , if it is scheduled by `cronjob` in `Linux`.

When i was running the command manually it is working file. Please find the command:

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppradeep --add-drop-database --routines --databases mnode_cm_data > pradeep11.sql
```

And also tried as below too:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql/mysqldump -uroot -ppradeep --add-drop-database --routines --databases mnode_cm_data > pradeep11.sql
```